# Finding eigenvalues without using eig function

Tags: python

I am finding the eigenvalues of the matrix without using the function (`eig`) in python. I do not know how to make a variable to store the unknown lambda.

```
def pre_determinant(matrix):
    x = symbols('x')
    x = float(x)
    for num in range(len(matrix)):
        matrix[num,num] -= x
    return matrix
```

Comment: Do you mean SciPy's `eig` function? Why wouldn't you use it? Libraries exist to solve common problems in their domains. Use them.

Comment: use gauss elimination or find the solutions of the characteristic equation

Comment: with `sympy`: `matrix.charpoly().nroots()`, by default also complex solutions are returned but you can add field constraints to fix the domain